# jquery .css background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been working on my website and I'm having trouble with setting the css of my background.

This is the code that i have right now. Im trying to use only jquery and not a css file.

```
$('<div id="klanbot_config">').css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: 792,
    top: -7,
    width: 199,
    height: 545,
    border: "3px gold solid",
    color: "white",
    "font-size": "10px",
}).appendTo("#centerbox2");
```

I tried doing background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQQgp.jpg'), but that did not work.

Comment: Check your console.

Comment: `"font-size"` can be substituted with `fontSize`, and the comma after `"10px"` can go too if you are interested in micromanaging your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried doing `background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Uc3QUrs.jpg')`, but that did not work.

You'd need to put the `url('...')` part in double-quotes:

```
background: "url('http://i.imgur.com/Uc3QUrs.jpg')"
```

Otherwise you're trying to call a function called `url()` and set the `background` to its return value.